# Change password of webdav user in Linux Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-management, user-accounts, webdav

I have a webdav setup in Ubuntu.

I tried to change one user password by doing:

```
sudo htpasswd users.password username
```

followed by:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now that user cannot login with the new password, nor even with the old password.

How should I change password for webdav users?

```
uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-16-237 4.4.0-79-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 17 19:58:14 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score -1):

This [has already been discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4240723/how-to-change-webdav-password-locally) in the stackoverflow community.

Furthermore it would be interesting, which Ubuntu version you are using and for which WebDAV realm the users password should be changed.

Comment: Question edited to include info you asked. What is a `WebDAV realm`?

Comment: The question/answer in the provided link is about Windows. I'm curious about Linux.

Comment: I do not understand where this makes a (big) difference, it is still done with the 'htdigest' command, except it won't have an '.exe' extension. At least for myself, the linked content was enough to do the task at hand.